# About Continuous Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a compact and normal operator over a Hilbert space and let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...$ be the eigenvalues of $T$ with $\lambda_0=0.$ How can I show that for each $u \in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(T))$  (the set of all continuous functions defined over the spectrum of $T$)

$u(T) =\sum_{i=0}^\infty u(\lambda_i)P_i$$

where $P_i$ is the orthonormal projection over the subspace $Ker(T-\lambda_i I)$

Also, I wondering which condition do I need to have $u(T)$ a compact operator??

Comment: What is your definition of $u(T)$?  Some would treat the right side of your equation *as* the definition.  I believe you will have $u(T)$ compact iff $u(0)=0$.